# Does discord.py do that continously?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to code a discord bot and when learning the module I am stuck here;

I mean in the code below will discord call on_message function whenever a message sent in the channels that bot has access to and will the on_reminder function be called without stopping until application closes?

Here's my code;

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    command_list={"!odev":command_odev,"!teslim":command_teslim,"!kontrol":command_kontrol}

    try:
        excep_src = "Geçersiz Komut!"
        msg2 = " "
        msg1 = " "
        if message.content.splitlines()[0].strip() not in command_list:
            raise Exception()

        msg1 = "Geçersiz girdi, lütfen komutu şu düzende belirtin:"
        excep_src=" "
        msg2=command_list[message.content.splitlines()[0].strip()]

        await message.channel.send(msg1)

    except:
        excep_src,msg1,msg2=excep_src,msg1,msg2

        await message.channel.send(f"""
{excep_src if 2 == len(excep_src.split()) else msg1}
{msg2}
            """)


## !odev yeni ödev verme
## !teslim ödev teslim etme
## !kontrol ödevi teslim edip etmediğini kontrol etme

@client.event
async def on_reminder():
    sleep(3600)
    kontrol()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

- `discord.on_message(message)` : "Called when a [Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.Message) is created and sent" so this event will be triggered whenever a message is sent in a channel the bot has access to.
- As for `on_reminder`, it's not an existing event so it won't be triggered. If you want it to run every hour, you might want to take at the [`task`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html) extension.